# Documentation comment for a Swift class extension

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, comments

I am extending `UIColor`, and trying to give [a description](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/ComentBlock.html) to the extended class.

My code is

```
/**
 - To store all colors
 - Naming Convention identifier: In lowerCamelCase with single name description
 - Naming Convention value: single name

 - example:  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.View.NonCompliant

 */
extension UIColor{

        /**
         - To specify all seperators' color
         */
        struct Seperators{
            static let commonSeperator = UIColor(red: 53.0/255.0, green: 126.0/255.0, blue: 167.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
}
```

But Xcode still shows the original description instead of the modified description.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: May be you can look at these: HeaderDoc & Doxygen, https://www.appcoda.com/documenting-source-code-in-xcode/

Comment: Still it is displaying inbuit descriptions only..

Comment: Pretty sure that you can't doc comment extensions. One consequence of them being anonymous. You can only document the things that are in the extension.

Comment: @Josh CasWell Ohh okay..  I thought there might be a way of doing it which i dont know.. Thanks though.. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use xcode's documentation. select method name and Xcode->Editor->Structure->Add Documentation. Xcode generate documentation for you.
or shourt cut alt + cmd + /

Comment: The problem is that xcode only generates the template, and doesn't add extra "///" when you add line. This means you have to take care of it yourself, which is quite annoying.